# split string after comma and till string ends- asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a string of type

> ishan,training

I want to split the string after "," i.e i want the output as

> training

NOTE: "," does not have a fixed index as the string value before "," is different at different times.

e.g ishant,marcela OR ishu,ponda OR amnarayan,mapusa etc...

From all the above strings i just need the part after ","

Comment: I'm not sure if what you want is to get the second word. I mean, if you've "a,b,c,d", you want to get "b,d"?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx):

```
string[] tokens = str.Split(',');
string last = tokens[tokens.Length - 1]
```

Or, a little simpler:

```
string last = str.Substring(str.LastIndexOf(',') + 1);
```

Comment: Or you may want to use Linq: str.Split(',').LastOrDefault()

Comment: @Kobi Thank for this very simple but best approach so far! I have made a good use of `str.Substring(str.LastIndexOf(',') + 1);` in my project which working just fine! thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

```
var arr = string.Split(",");
var result = arr[arr.length-1];
```

Comment: This will only give the last item. Is that what they want? From the title it seams they what everything after the comma. What if the string is 1,2,3,4,5?

Answer (score 2):

`sourcestring.Substring(sourcestring.IndexOf(','))`. You might want to check `sourcestring.IndexOf(',')` for `-1` for strings without `,`.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question has already been answered, but you can use linq:

```
string str = "1,2,3,4,5";
str.Split(',').LastOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

Although there are several comments mentioning the issue of multiple commas being found, there doesn't seem to be any mention of the solution for that:

```
string input = "1,2,3,4,5";
if (input.IndexOf(',') > 0)
{
    string afterFirstComma = input.Split(new char[] { ',' }, 2)[1];
}
```

This will make `afterFirstComma` equal to "2,3,4,5"

Answer (score 0):

Use `String.Split(",")` assign the result in to a string array and use what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Heres a VB version. I'm sure its easy to translate to C# though

```
 Dim str as string = "ishan,training"
 str = str.split(",")(1)

 return str
```

Comment: That works for the example above but, doesn't consider a string with multiple commas

Comment: Ah sorry, this might be better:.Split(",").Reverse(0)